# php-sha3 not working since upgrade to 5.4

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-12.04, sha-3

I upgraded my PHP installation to:

```
 PHP Version 5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1
```

It broke my install of https://github.com/strawbrary/php-sha3. I tried to recompile it, but had no luck. I have the file linked in my php.ini file. My phpinfo() is not showing any sign that sha3 is installed.

When I run `phpize` on the server when compiling sha3 I get:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

However when I look at my phpinfo file I get:

```
PHP API         20100412
PHP Extension   20100525
Zend Extension  220100525
```

Here is how I recompiled the plugin:

```
    root@deff:/# git clone https://github.com/strawbrary/php-sha3
Cloning into 'php-sha3'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 42, done.
remote: Total 42 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (42/42), done.
root@deff:/# cd php-sha3/
root@deff:/php-sha3# phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
root@deff:/php-sha3# ./configure --enable-sha3
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking Whether to enable SHA3 support... yes, shared
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
root@deff:/php-sha3# make
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-sha3/php_sha3.c -o php_sha3.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-sha3/php_sha3.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_sha3.o
In file included from /usr/include/php5/main/php.h:33:0,
                 from /php-sha3/php_sha3.c:5:
/usr/include/php5/main/php_config.h:2126:0: warning: "PACKAGE_NAME" redefined [enabled by default]
/php-sha3/config.h:48:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/include/php5/main/php_config.h:2138:0: warning: "PACKAGE_VERSION" redefined [enabled by default]
/php-sha3/config.h:60:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/php5/ext/hash/php_hash_types.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/include/php5/ext/hash/php_hash.h:25,
                 from /php-sha3/php_sha3.c:7:
./config.h:48:0: warning: "PACKAGE_NAME" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/php5/main/../main/php_config.h:2126:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
./config.h:60:0: warning: "PACKAGE_VERSION" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/php5/main/../main/php_config.h:2138:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-sha3/KeccakNISTInterface.c -o KeccakNISTInterface.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-sha3/KeccakNISTInterface.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/KeccakNISTInterface.o
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-sha3/KeccakSponge.c -o KeccakSponge.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-sha3/KeccakSponge.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/KeccakSponge.o
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c -o KeccakF-1600-opt64.lo 
ILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c -o KeccakF-1600-opt64.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/php-sha3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/KeccakF-1600-opt64.o
r/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/KeccakF-1600-opt64.o
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-sha3/include -I/php-sha3/main -I/php-sha3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o sha3.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /php-sha3/modules  php_sha3.lo KeccakNISTInterface.lo KeccakSponge.lo KeccakF-1600-opt64.lo 
libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/php_sha3.o .libs/KeccakNISTInterface.o .libs/KeccakSponge.o .libs/KeccakF-1600-opt64.o    -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,sha3.so -o .libs/sha3.so
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "sha3.la" && ln -s "../sha3.la" "sha3.la" )
/bin/bash /php-sha3/libtool --mode=install cp ./sha3.la /php-sha3/modules
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/sha3.so /php-sha3/modules/sha3.so
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/sha3.lai /php-sha3/modules/sha3.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /php-sha3/modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /php-sha3/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

root@deff:/php-sha3# make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/
root@deff:/php-sha3# sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Have you tried recompiling it against the new version of PHP? What do you mean by "reset"? Do you get any notices if you try running `php -v` (bad extensions often emit a warning at this point)?

Comment: Yes I meant recompile it when I said restart. When I run php -v I get no error. I have however noticed that the configuring Api and Zend No do not match the server. More info above.

Comment: Maybe `phpize` is compiling against the wrong PHP? I seem to remember there are options for this, have a look at help or the man page? Also, it would be worth editing into your question the steps you are taking to recompile - you may be doing something wrong, but it would be hard for someone to say without seeing those steps.

Comment: @halfer I just finished posting how I installed it.

Comment: Alright, check your php.ini to ensure you are loading from the explicit path `/php-sha3/modules/sha3.so`. Also do `phpize --help` or `man phpize` to see how to point to your PHP installation - I think you are right that the API version thing is the problem.

Comment: when I run man phpize I get that the `VERSION INFORMATION
       This manpage describes php, version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9.` I think this is my problem. I need it to be `PHP Version 5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1`

Comment: Do `which phpize` to see the location of the binary you are running, then `locate phpize | less` to see if there is another one that is not in your system path?

Comment: I updated phpize and it didn't work. I was never able to get it working with `PHP Version 5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1`

Comment: Well, don't give up `:-)`. Try searching for "phpize PHP API" or "phpize 20100412 Ubuntu 5.4" etc. Someone is bound to have fixed either the general problem, or this specific one.

Comment: I gave up.. I reloaded my server with an updated version of ubuntu and then just got the updated version of php from the ubuntu apt-get. I think it was a problem with the sury.org~precise+1 verision.

Comment: Ah fair enough, so long as you got the install you needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with installing PHP Version 5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1. I has to do with a mismatch with the php API version. BE WARNED. Do not update to Version 5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1. Try to update from the official php repository.